# Word boundary won't match the beginning or end in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I'm getting unexpected results with this code:

```
'foo'.match(new RegExp('\bfoo\b')); // Returns null
```

Why is this returning `null` while this one returns "foo"?

```
'foo'.match(new RegExp('foo')); // Returns "foo"
```

Doesn't a word boundary marker match the beginning and end as well?

EDIT: I need the regular expression itself to be a string because I am injecting variables into it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Escape the backslashes

```
'foo'.match(new RegExp('\\bfoo\\b'));
```

Comment: Do you know why the backslash for this needs to be escaped but it doesn't for something like  getting a forward slash

Answer (score -2):

Don't wrap it in quotes... instead, do this:-

```
'foo'.match(new RegExp(/\bfoo\b/))
```

Comment: I need it to be a string because I'm dropping in values.

Comment: @mattalexx: That really should be part of your question if you want it to persist here and be useful to others.